# Partial derivative of a piece-wise function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

$f(x,y)$ is:

$\frac{3xy+5y^3}{x^2+y^2} $ if $(x,y) \neq 0$

$0$ if $(x,y) = 0$.

Would $f_y$ be the partial derivative of $0$, which is $0$,  or the partial of $ \frac{3xy+5y^3}{x^2+y^2} $ with respect to $y$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the proper way of thinking. To compute the partial derivative, you have to calculate
$$
f_y(x,y) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x,y+t) - f(x,y)}{t}.
$$
When $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, you can use the usual rules for differentiation since the denominator does not vanish. However, when $(x,y) = (0,0)$, you need to go back to this rule, which means you need to evaluate the limit
$$
f_y(0,0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(0,t) - f(0,0)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{5t^3}{t^2} - 0}{t} = 5. 
$$
The question whether this equals the limit when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ of the partial derivative of $\frac{3xy + 5y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ with respect to $y$ is another one; it is the discussion about the continuity of $f_y$ at $(0,0)$, not its definition.

Hope that helps,